# android 6 system alert permission..!

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm giving several runtime premission for android 6 but on every restart of device or onclick to service start a dialog appears System alert and read contact permission on it.
my application works in background(as service called by broadcast after the restart) **this is the first permission and i noticed that there is not never ask again option on it** [image]

**and this is the second system alert thing that i was saying**
[image]

**NOW
 how i can give the permission once and never asks again i'm already checking the permission but this is different thing and it is just for the read contact permission**

Comment: i thing they are removing background services for long running, u need to take a look at the link, it considers long running service as an malicious app behavior. U must use JobService for such tasks. in any case background serivice wont run for longer duration in any case. https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

Comment: i want my service to work 24 hours and i need it to work on <api 21

Comment: read the whole doc, u need to handle versions with api level

Comment: wait posting an answer

Comment: Do you have a special version of Android running? Seems weird.

Comment: @Christopher no its android 6 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already on the documentation of Android [android.developer.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html)

*The way Android makes the requests depends on the system version, and the system version targeted by your app:*

*If the device is running **Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher**, and the app's **targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher**, the app requests permissions from the user at run-time. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, so the app needs to check whether it has the permissions every time it accesses permission-protected APIs. For more information about requesting permissions in your app, see the Working with System Permissions training guide.*

It is possible that you set the `app's targetSdkVersion is 22 or lower`

as mentioned:

*If the device is running Android 5.1.1 (API level 22) or lower, or the app's targetSdkVersion is 22 or lower, the system asks the user to grant the permissions when the user installs the app. If you add a new permission to an updated version of the app, the system asks the user to grant that permission when the user updates the app. Once the user installs the app, the only way they can revoke the permission is by uninstalling the app.*

You could also use my Custom Permission Class

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class PermissionUtil {

    private static final String TAG = PermissionUtil.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public static final int READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    public static final int RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 4;

    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_WRITE_STORAGE = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_AUDIO = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_CAMERA = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    PermissionUtil() { }

    /**
     * SAMPLER
     * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
     * <p/>
     * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
     *
     * @param activity the mContext from which permissions are checked
     */
    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_WRITE_STORAGE,
                    WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
            );
        }
    }

    public static void verrifyReadStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE[0]);
        if (isPermissionDenied(permission)) {
            processPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE[0], PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public static void verrifyWriteStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS_WRITE_STORAGE[0]);
        if (isPermissionDenied(permission)) {
            processPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS_WRITE_STORAGE[0], PERMISSIONS_WRITE_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public static void verrifyRecordAudioPermissions(Activity activity) {
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS_AUDIO[0]);
        if (isPermissionDenied(permission)) {
            processPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS_AUDIO[0], PERMISSIONS_AUDIO, RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public static void verrifyCameraPermissions(Activity activity) {
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS_CAMERA[0]);
        if (isPermissionDenied(permission)) {
            processPermission(activity, PERMISSIONS_CAMERA[0], PERMISSIONS_CAMERA, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPermissionDenied(int permission) {
        return permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private static void processPermission(Activity activity, String permissionManifest, String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permissionManifest)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale is invoked " + permissionManifest);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode);
            Log.e(TAG, "requestPermissions is invoked " + permissionManifest);
        }
    }

    /**
     * SAMPLER
     * Request the permissions you need
        If your app doesn't already have the permission it needs, the app must call one of the requestPermissions() methods to request the appropriate permissions.
        Your app passes the permissions it wants, and also an integer request code that you specify to identify this permission request.
        This method functions asynchronously: it returns right away, and after the user responds to the dialog box,
        the system calls the app's callback method with the results, passing the same request code that the app passed to requestPermissions().
     * @param activity - you mContext
     */
    public static void verifyShowRequestPrompt(Activity activity) {
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            Log.e(TAG, "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale is invoked");
        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }

    /**
     * ABOVE CODES is not used
     * @param activity
     */

    public static void initPermissions(final Activity activity) {
        // The request code used in ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()
        // and returned in the Activity's onRequestPermissionsResult()
        // int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
        if(!hasPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS)) {
            showMessageOKCancel(activity, "These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (!hasPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS)) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        setGAlleryPermissionIntent();
    }

    public static void initPermissions(final Context context) {
        // The request code used in ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()
        // and returned in the Activity's onRequestPermissionsResult()
        // int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
        if(!hasPermissions(context, PERMISSIONS)) {
            showMessageOKCancel(context, "These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (!hasPermissions(context, PERMISSIONS)) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        setGAlleryPermissionIntent();
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(final Context context, final String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                     return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void showMessageOKCancel(Context context, String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    public static void setGAlleryPermissionIntent() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24){
            try{
                Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                m.invoke(null);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just call this on your activity.

```
   void onCreate(...) {
      PermissionUtil.verrifyReadStoragePermissions(this);
      ...
   }
```

Comment: I tried this code but still the system warning block my service to run

Comment: You should try to handle and check this on your BackGround Services and try to implement this PermissionUtil with the Current Context you had on your  Service.

Comment: this method verrifyReadStoragePermissions needs activity

Comment: public static void verrifyReadStoragePermissions(**Activity activity**)